# Flash: MovieClip dissappears after frame change

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

So I have a button movieclip, it has two frames inside it.

`onRollOver()` I switch to frame 2 and `onRollOut()` I return to frame 1. The problem is that at run-time I draw two new movieclips inside this and alter their depths using `swapDepths()` so they appear below the existing movieclip.

The problem is that after you roll-over and then roll-out, the movieclips dissappear. I am assuming this is because the MovieClips I swapped their depths with get redrawn over my MovieClips's depths.

How could I avoid this behaviour? The MovieClips I draw at run-time must be below everything else inside the button MovieClip, and I can't have a holder MovieClip inside the button in which to situate them.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds wildly similar to a problem I've had before.

First, have you called gotoAndStop(2) and gotoAndStop(1) when you swap the frame? If you don't, and there isn't actionscript in the movieclip to stop playback, weird things happen... [NOTE: That was AS3...AS2 may have different code, so you'll have to look into that.]

That aside, if you're wanted to control the depth of the MovieClip, and you have Flash Professional I would recommending using layers. Put each MovieClip in its own layer, and then order them based on which you want above, and which you want below. I'm sure you can do something similar in other Flash IDEs.

I hope one (or both) of those helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, I am indeed using `gotoAndStop()` and am using multiple layers, the problem is that the extra movieclips are being drawn at runtime and swapped with existing movieclips. It appears that when you return to frame 1 the movieclips I swapped with get redrawn on the layer they first started and overwrite my runtime movieclips.

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the z index of the object via code? http://www.actionscript.org/forums/archive/index.php3/t-181822.html [Being a more visual-type person, I generally create all the objects I want to use in design time, to ensure I don't have any such issues. However, that's just my personal preference.]